# python add number for each line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing input of data to a txt file for some student data and I wanted to give each line of data a number when its added to the text file, thought I could use "count" somehow. So it can be used as a registration number for each student and append it to the txt. So the txt file will contain, firstname, surnname, postcode, gender, age, house, science groups, registration number. Ive broken down part of script so it just prints name,postcode and registration number. I would like the registration number to increment each time it loops. Now it prints ..
Name Scott Postcode nn5 Registration Number 1

```
moredata ="Y"
while moredata == "Y":

    name=input("enter name ")
    postcode=input("enter postcode ")


    print("Name ",name, "PostCode", postcode, "Registration Number ", name.count(name))

    moredata=input("y or n")
    moredata=moredata.upper()
```

Comment: Your question is mostly code. Where exactly do you want the number to appear? A comment in the code would help. Also, do you know the number of students? You can use [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#func-range).

Comment: it would be good to have it added in the txt file and also when printing it. So far the txt file looks like                                                
scott,harris,nn5 ,M,14,Blake House,
scott,Spence,nn5 ,M,14,Blake House,                                                                     trying to get it to look something like                                                                    scott,harris,nn5 ,M,14,Blake House,1
scott,Spence,nn5 ,M,14,Blake House,2 etc             idea is to just keep adding students when needed there is no set number of them

Comment: Please use the [Edit] button to include all relevant information in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a `count` variable outside of the loop and increment it by `1` every time the loop runs.

Comment: thanks Colin I've tried adding count = count +1 but can't seem to get it working.

Comment: you haven't initialized `count` anywhere

Comment: also "can't seem to get it working" is not a useful statement. What error are you getting?